# How do I add a Watchkit target to an iOS app in Xcode 9?

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit

Up to Xcode 8, I could add a WatchKit target by File > New > Target. Watchkit would be an option.

I can't find this in Xcode 9.4.1. I searched  thru the WWDC videos, and will keep looking.

Has anyone found a method?

Answer (score 1):

The functionality has moved slightly:

Use File > New > Project.

Then on this screen:

[image]

Select WatchOS

[image]

Then select iOS App with WatchKit App.